# How can I see who voted to close my question?

Tags: support, vote-to-close

I believe that someone incorrectly voted to close my question. Do I have any recourse? Is it possible to see who voted to close a question?

Comment: Which question?

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you can see that when your question is actually closed. The names are listed there.

You cannot see that earlier, and it should not be important.

Comment: I love how @PieterGoosen edited this answer.

Comment: @kaiser toscho had a slight stutter there, hahaha :-)